# как понимать условие данной простой задачи?

Tags: c++

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

пытаюсь вникнуть уже 20 минут, безрезультатно

Comment: От тебя просто просят проверить, что последовательность - неубывающая.

Comment: Экстремальное свойство = массив отсортирован)

Answer (score 3):

Очень витьевато просят проверить, что массив a отсортирован по возрастанию.
Детальней - условие будет нарушено если найдется два элемента массива таких, что более ранний больше более позднего.

Answer (score 2):

у вас есть массив чисел `arr`

из которого вы должны получить `n^2` чисел по указанной выше формуле

и найти минимальное из них

если минимальное число больше нуля - условие экстримальности выполняется

например в примере 1) `1 2` вы получаете

```
x(1, 2) = arr[2] - arr[1] = 1 > 0 - yes
x(2, 1) = 9001
```

а в примере 2) `2 1 3 4` получаете

```
arr[2] - arr[1] = -1 < 0 - no
```

а по сути условие с `<= 0` означает, что любое право число должно быть не меньше любого левого числа в массиве, т.е. последовательность в массиве не убывающая